# How to dynamically position paragraph at beginning of centred heading

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

The question trivial, but when I started to think about it I could not find an easy and correct way out.

I want to have my Heading to be centred and then I want to keep my paragraph aligned to the start of Heading. Also *I want the paragraph to be responsively aligned to Heading on all devices down to 770px*

**What I would like to avoid**

1. JS approach
2. Brutal breakpoints approach

**What I would like to to do**

1. Some sass mixin functionality
2. Some HTML container logic
3. Some unknown to me aligning method

**Centred for default width**

[image]

**Width becomes larger**

[image]

```css
.container .intro-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/M7gDO41.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Shrikhand; }
  .container .intro-panel h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .container .intro-panel p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25.5%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center; }
  .container .intro-panel .button-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 160px; }
    .container .intro-panel .button-wrap .see-more {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 280px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 44px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 140px;
      background-color: #003DE8;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro-panel" data-tilt>
      <h1 class="intro-name title">Edgars Pavuls</h1>
      <p>Professinal Web Application Developer</p>
      <div class="button-wrap">
          <div class="vibrate-3 see-more">
              See More
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i already did research this,
I can post my code down here if it is helpflul to anyone.

Comment: That's what you are supposed to to...in fact the solution is trivially simple...if you think about it.

Comment: Haha, then enlighten me, because I have done my part of FE, but I could not solve this simple issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
       <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
       <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
    </div>
</div>

.container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/i3RlmpoZMD

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by wrapping your title and text in an inline-block element and then left aligning your text

Please note if your text should be longer than your title, that will be centred and the title left aligned to that - ie the longest item will be centred

```css
.outer {
  /* put background on here */
  text-align: center;
}

.centre {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="centre">
    <h1 class="heading">This is some long text</h1>
    <p class="text">some other text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help, worked like a charm. 
 text-align: left; on .centre div did the trick.